# Runtime.exec() in Android hangs

Tags: android, runtime, exec, android-2.2-froyo

When I try to exec an external script in this way:

```
try {
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
        new String[] { "/system/bin/sh", "./myscript.sh" },
        null,
        "/data/mydir",
    );
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Sometimes the script gets executed, but most often my app hangs a couple of seconds until Android says my app is unresponsive and it needs to kill it.

My question is, what may be happening. The script *is* running sometimes, and there is *no* exception being thrown, it just hangs. I'm at a loss as to what's happening. I'm using Froyo (2.2.1 I think).

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm I guess something to do with android threading. Have you tried doing this in the a thread.

Comment: Do you think so? Maybe, there's some kind of deadlock happening, dunno. You're right, I'll give it its own thread. :-)

Comment: Check out the process class doc developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Process.html. The overview seems useful and explains why it might be blocking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation you should read the err and out stream of the process.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Process.html

I think something like the following will solve your problem.

```
class Reader extends Thread
{
    InputStream is;

    Reader(InputStream is){
        this.is = is;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            InputStreamReader inStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inStreamReader);
            String line=null;
            while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null){
                // log here   
            }
        } catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();  
        }
    }
}
```

Use the above class in your code like this

```
try {
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
        new String[] { "/system/bin/sh", "./myscript.sh" },
        null,
        "/data/mydir",
    );
    Reader err = new Reader(process.getErrorStream());
    Reader output = new Reader(process.getInputStream());

    err.start();
    outout.start();

} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
} finally {
    process.destroy();
}
```